# FILTER with MIN in SPARQL

Tags: sparql, rdf

I am writing following SPARQL query.

```
select ?o1, ?o2, ?e from <http://ndssl.bi.vt.edu/chicago/> 
where{
?s <http://ndssl.bi.vt.edu/chicago/vocab/dendrogram_infector_pid> ?o1.
?s <http://ndssl.bi.vt.edu/chicago/vocab/dendrogram_infectee_pid> ?o2.
?s <http://ndssl.bi.vt.edu/chicago/vocab/dendrogram_iteration> '0'^^xsd:decimal.
?s <http://ndssl.bi.vt.edu/chicago/vocab/dendrogram_exposureday> ?e.
?s1 <http://ndssl.bi.vt.edu/chicago/vocab/contactnetwork_pid1> ?o1.
?s1 <http://ndssl.bi.vt.edu/chicago/vocab/contactnetwork_pid2> ?o2.
?s1 <http://ndssl.bi.vt.edu/chicago/vocab/contactnetwork_acttype1> '5'^^xsd:decimal.
?s1 <http://ndssl.bi.vt.edu/chicago/vocab/contactnetwork_acttype1> '5'^^xsd:decimal
}
```

Query returns result like below.

```
<http://ndssl.bi.vt.edu/chicago/person/pid#449563560>   <http://ndssl.bi.vt.edu/chicago/person/pid#446718746>   32
<http://ndssl.bi.vt.edu/chicago/person/pid#449563560>   <http://ndssl.bi.vt.edu/chicago/person/pid#446734805>   5
<http://ndssl.bi.vt.edu/chicago/person/pid#450309500>   <http://ndssl.bi.vt.edu/chicago/person/pid#450261482>   30
```

I want only the triple where "?e" is minimum. That means following:

```
<http://ndssl.bi.vt.edu/chicago/person/pid#449563560>   <http://ndssl.bi.vt.edu/chicago/person/pid#446734805>   5
```

How can I do it? I tried following but it does not work.

```
.............
?s <http://ndssl.bi.vt.edu/chicago/vocab/dendrogram_exposureday> ?e.FILTER (MIN (?e))
.............
```

I need to find the minimum value of object "?e" within "WHERE" clause because some other part of the query depends on it.

Comment: `ORDER BY ASC(?e) LIMIT 1`

Comment: Why is this tagged jena?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get results with a minimal value, the easiest thing to do is to sort by that value and limit the number of solutions to one.  For instance (you should be able to apply this technique to your query):

```sql
select ?x {
  values ?x { 8 2 0 2 -3 1 5 }
}
order by ?x
limit 1
```

This will produce -3 as the sole result because it was first after the results were ordered, and only the first result was admitted by the limit.